# flip effect working on firefox but not on chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox

i have try to make flip effect through css and html only.its working fine on Firefox but not working on chrome.I have also try webkit prefix but not working can anybody help me.its urgent.here the code

```
  .flip3D{
  width: 240px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 10 px;
  float: left;
  }
  .flip3D > .front{
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-transform: perspective( 600px ) rotateY( 0deg);
  transform: perspective( 600px ) rotateY( 0deg);
  background-color: #D8D2D2;
  width: 180px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 7px;
  color: black;
  -webkit-backface-visibility:hidden;
  backface-visibility:hidden;
  transition: -webkit-transform 0.5s ;linear 0s;
  transition: transform 0.5s ;linear 0s;
  }
  .flip3D > .back{
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-transform: perspective( 600px ) rotateY( 180deg);
  transform:perspective( 600px ) rotateY( 180deg);
  background-color:#30D2FF;
  width: 180px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 7px;
  color: white;
  -webkit-backface-visibility:hidden;
  backface-visibility:hidden;
  transition: -webkit-transform 0.5s ;linear 0s;
  transition: transform 0.5s ;linear 0s;
  }
  .flip3D:hover > .front{
  transform:perspective( 600px ) rotateY( -180deg);
  }
  .flip3D:hover > .back{
  transform:perspective( 600px ) rotateY( 0deg);
  }
```

html code:

```
    <div class="flip3D">
    <div class="back">box 1 back</div>
    <div class="front">box 1 front</div>``
    </div>
```

Comment: Don't forget to add -webkit to your hover transforms.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add the `-webkit-` prefix to everything. After adding it to the below code it seems to work fine,

```
.flip3D:hover > .front{
  transform:perspective( 600px ) rotateY( -180deg);
    -webkit-transform:perspective( 600px ) rotateY( -180deg);
  }
  .flip3D:hover > .back{
  transform:perspective( 600px ) rotateY( 0deg);
    -webkit-transform:perspective( 600px ) rotateY( 0deg);
  }
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/b46ns/3/)

Note: I messed up one of the styles it is now fixed.

Comment: @Danko in your fiddle it is not doing anything, where am I missing the prefix?

Answer (score 3):

Here's your answer man. Add `-webkit` prefix to `transform` property. You missed it twice at the end for those hover styles. And check the fiddle for your reference. [JS FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/fCJ3x/1/)

```
.flip3D:hover > .front{
    -webkit-transform:perspective( 600px ) rotateY( -180deg);
}
.flip3D:hover > .back{
    -webkit-transform:perspective( 600px ) rotateY( 0deg);
 }
```